# Trouble with closure in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

The process: In the game I'm making, there's a *for* loop that's supposed to save a value in an array. That value changes with each iteration. The problem: when the loop is done running, every element of the array is identical, all showing the most recent value.
I know this issue is common, and I've made so many different tweaks and attempts at solving it over the past 2 days.

0) I tried separating things into separate functions as much as possible.
1) I tried defining my loop counters with "let" so they would have a local scope.
2) I tried wrapping my assignment in a self-executing function so it would happen immediately, preserving the value of currentlyOn before the next loop iteration changes it. My counter is the variable c.

```
(function(c2, currentlyOn2) {
  onAtSameTime[c2] = currentlyOn2;
  return 0;
})(c, currentlyOn);
```

3) I tried attempt #2 with the added feature of returning a function, which still didn't save the value of currentlyOn. This option isn't a good one for me anyway, because the whole point is that I'm doing some computations ahead of time so my game will have a quick animation loop.

```
onAtSameTime[c] = (function(currentlyOn2) {
  return function() {
    return currentlyOn2;
  };
})(currentlyOn);
```

I'm tired of beating my head against this wall. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

For more details, check out the [jsfiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/inthse/az6ruaq4/). The problem area is at line 59, using a simple assignment:

```
onAtSameTime[c] = currentlyOn;
```

Comment: currentlyOn is merely a pointer to where the value for the array is stored. Every [c] index will contain the same pointer, and as a result will then also access the same value. Use localized arrays instead of currentlyOn to avoid this, or consider refactoring your approach to avoid one array when there should be many.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with closures. There are no functions that are executed after your loops. You seem to have problems with the array iteration, array cloning, or your algorithm.

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Post your code **here**, not just at jsfiddle. You can make it executable with [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onAtSameTime[c] = currentlyOn;` sets `onAtSameTime[c]` equal to the *reference* of `currentlyOn`, since `currentlyOn` is an array, not a primitive value. That reference gets updated with each iteration. You could work around that by creating a copy of the array before adding it to the `onAtSameTime` array. Something like `onAtSameTime[c] = [].concat(currentlyOn);` would do the trick.

See this fork of your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2by787y/

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation! Your answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy from `currentlyOn` for assigning to `onAtSameTime[c]`. This keeps the values, but does not keep the reference to the same array.

```
onAtSameTime[c] = currentlyOn.slice(); // use copy
```

```js
"use strict";
function log(text) {
    document.getElementById("logbox").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(text) + "<br>";
    return 0;
}

function whichSwitchesAreOn() {
    var currentlyOn = [],
        flickedSet,
        flickedOne,
        turningOnCheck;

    for (var c = 0; c < switchesToggled.length; c++) {
        flickedSet = switchesToggled[c];
        for (var d = 0; d < flickedSet.length; d++) {
            flickedOne = flickedSet[d];
            turningOnCheck = currentlyOn.indexOf(flickedOne);
            if (turningOnCheck == -1) {
                currentlyOn.push(flickedOne);
            } else {
                currentlyOn.splice(turningOnCheck, 1);
            }
        }
        log("currentlyOn: " + currentlyOn);
        onAtSameTime[c] = currentlyOn.slice(); // use copy
    }
    return 0;
}

var switchesToggled = [[0], [1, 2], [0], [2], []],
    onAtSameTime = [];

whichSwitchesAreOn();
log(onAtSameTime);
```

```html
<div id="logbox"></div>
```

Comment: `onAtSameTime[c] = currentlyOn.slice();` is simpler and one line shorter

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I accepted Eric Gibby's answer because it had more detail to the explanation, but your answer also works.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have tried let?

Did you have let currentlyOn = [] inside of the for loop?

```
  for(var c = 0; c < switchesToggled.length; c++) {
      let currentlyOn = [];
```

Comment: it is working with just an assignment without `let`.

Comment: Unfortunately, each iteration of the loop must be able to remember the previous value of currentlyOn, so I can't define it within the loop.